# Broken links after upgrading to 2.3.3

Tags: upgrade

I've recently upgraded to 2.3.3 via Installatron on cpanel, now when I visit my home page I have links to other product pages within the navbar and links to the same pages from images that populate the home page.

The links from the navbar do not work but point to the same page as the image links which do work.

The address bar redirection addressees are exactly the same but the images link you get to view the particular product but using the nav links return a 'The page isn’t redirecting properly' error.
I've run php bin/magento -> indexer:reindex -> cache:flush -> setup:upgrade
Any ideas?

Comment: check-in log file.

Comment: would you mind to give some error images?

Answer (score 0):

Please run Following Commands after Upgrade:

```
composer update
```

Then

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Then

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Then

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Then

```
php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f && chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Hope this will solve your problem!!

Comment: I went through all those steps but on the second command I don't think it completes as this is how far in it goes... Repositories code generation... 1/7 [==>-----------------]  14% < 1 sec 76.5 MiB[aslbathr@nickel public_html]$ all the other command run and finish but not the home page isn't loading properly the header is only basic text and a few images randomly placed

Comment: First we need to resolve this issue. Can you please share logs.

Comment: Could you explain which logs and where?

Comment: Go to Root Directory then > var > log

Comment: Download all logs and See the Issues there.

Comment: This should be a link to the log files if you are able to still have a look? https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhpnMQHnyZbOaHzRrt7P43sNBks?e=QlxOY0 BTW I've restored the site to before I tried your commands today

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade our Magento store using only the command line and the broken links issue was solved.

I'm not sure why, but installing via Installatron on Cpanel was the cause of the broken links?